# Web Scraping: Error handling with non existent values while scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

- Scraper code below

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Address', 'Contact'])
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    url = 'www.website.com'
    driver.get(url)
    
    for _ in range(200):
        
        print('url, driver, window, driver.get INITIALIZED', 'DF created')
    
    
    
    
    
        name = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pflist-itemtitle')
        address = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pflist-address')
        contact = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='tel:']")
        print('variables to name, address, contact ASSIGNED')
    
    
        #Get names into a list
        name_list = []
        for a in range(len(name)):
            name_list.append(name[a].text)
            print('name scraped')
    
        address_list = []
        for b in range(len(address)):
            address_list.append(address[b].text)
            print('Address scraped')
    
        contact_list = []
        for c in range(len(contact)):
            contact_list.append(contact[c].text)
            print('Contact scraped')
    
    
        
        data_tuples = list(zip(name_list[0:], address_list[0:], contact_list[0:])) # everything is paired together
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=['Name', 'Address', 'Contact']) #creates temporary dataframe of each tuple in the field_listingtype
        df = df.append(temp_df)
        print('Data stored in dataframe')
    
    
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
    
        element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Next »')
    
        print('Is the button enabled : ' + str(element.is_enabled()))
        print('Is the button visible : ' + str(element.is_displayed()))
    
        element.click()
        print('Next is clicked')
        print('Finished scraping')
```

There are around 200 pages needed to scrape, with same format. Hence the for loop. Every page has around 70 contact cards, with Name, address, contact. I got the selenium elements working with those three, I have tested. It seemed ok when I tested for two pages. Now, I left everything working and once done, it has successfully scraped all 200 pages. I cross-referenced the numbers with the website and what I got in DF. Apparently there were some contact cards that did not have a phone number attached, and python attached the next available number to the contact without one. Hence all the numbers are not shifted and not for the correct contact. How can I avoid this, with some sort of an 'if' statement, that when the phone number element is not available, it just attaches some sort of a string of 'not available" in the phone number list?

- Another question. I noticed it sometimes missed entirely to scrape a contact or two. Could that be that it didn't make it in in time, because this time the page loaded quicker then other times? Thank in advance.

Comment: Can you share URL? Maybe solution with `beautifulsoup` will be enough...

Answer (score 0):

This is programmatical mistake. Look what you are doing is take all the names and save in list and so on with address and phone number and you are assuming that name will be correspond to address and phone number at respective location but imagine if a value is missing like in you case, the correspondence will be affected.

What you need to do is to use a single for loop either to name or address i.e. preferable to name because there is very little or no chance of missing name. So, loop to length of name.

```
name_List=[]
contact_List=[]
address_List=[]
i=0
while i<len(name):
    name_List.append(name[i].text)
    contac_List.append(contact[i].text)
    address_List.append(address[i].text)
    i=i+1
```

This will make sure your name_List, contact_List and address_List values are corresponds to each other. So for any missing value your list will store null or empty string at that location.